# africa dataset from Amelia package

Tags: r, package, load

`Amelia` has a dataset named `'africa'` and I'm trying to load it. `airquality` dataset works fine, but I want to know (1) how I can load datasets from the packages, and (2) to see what datasets are in that package, in order to choose the most accurrate dataset for a specific problem that I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets answer your questions the other way around. the `data` command is what you need.

2) To see the datasets in a package use:

```
data(package = "Amelia")
```

1) to load a dataset from a package without loading the package use:

```
data("africa", package = "Amelia")
```