# Can't load "freetrade" data from Amelia package in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Markdown to generate a report.

I have a markdown chunk as :

````
```{r}
library(Amelia)
df <- freetrade
```
````

When I proceed to knit the document, I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'freetrade' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

The same commands work well in R Studio's console. So I think it should load without any issues.

How can I resolve this?

I apologize if this is a repeated question.

Comment: It might be that the markdown document doesn't think the directory with the file is it's home directory.

Comment: @aginensky I also tried `data("freetrade", package="Amelia")` but this just loads the string `freetrade` in `df`. Is it possible to fix the directory of rmarkdown? I have never had this issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046182/africa-dataset-from-amelia-package).

I had to do the following steps:

````
```{r}
library(Amelia)
data("freetrade", package="Amelia") # load the data using data command
df <- freetrade
```
````